# How to secure Rails API requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an API only rails app and another angular app as frontend

Currently I'm securing the API by sending X-APP-Token with each request on headers

The other APIs which has logged in user has X-User-Token on headers as (JWT)

My question here, with each request sent from angular, the token are exposed on headers and anyone can have access to them

How can i secure these tokens from both front-end and back-end perspective ? like salting and encrypting so that if someone stole that token, it should be useless

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security has many layers but there is some stuff that you definitely need to include while securing your API here are some of the more important security measures based on my experience:

1. Access control or Role-based control, this is crucial if you want to secure your API, you need to include some sort of 'Policies' that helps you to manage access to resources within your API in order to secure your data (These too are good options if you ask me [Pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit), [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan), both are good although I prefer **Pundit**), this is one way to avoid that a user/cracker using another user access key/token gain access to a resource that is not part of his 'domain'.
2. You need to add the proper security headers to each backend response, this configuration depends on your API and your app, with that said you can add the code below in your application controller for example (the below is a good example of default configuration):

```rb
before_action :set_headers

  def set_headers
    response.set_header('Referrer-Policy', 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin')
    response.set_header('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff')
    response.set_header('X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN')
    response.set_header('X-XSS-Protection', '1; mode=block')
    response.set_header('Content-Security-Policy', "default-src 'self' https:; " \
        "img-src 'self' https:" \
        "media-src 'none'; " \
        "object-src 'none'; " \
        "script-src 'self'; " \
        "style-src 'self' ")
  end
```

3. Since you are in `rails 5.x` you can go to the configuration of your env lets say production.rb and add the following line: `config.force_ssl = true`, this will force all connections against your API through `HTTPS` and it will also add this response header `strict-transport-security` which increment security, be aware that if you try to reach your API via `HTTP` your API will try to force `HTTPS` and in some scenarios return a code of `301` which means redirected this is a good hint in case you have a health check.
4. Definitely you need to take care of common issues like Insecure Direct Object Reference (IDOR), this issue as his name indicates is when you have direct references to private resources, let's say in the URL of your app you have something like `***/shop/23`, where `23` is the autoincrement id of your model I think I don't need to explain why is that wrong, from that moment you can be exposed to enumeration attacks, access to info (which you should avoid with authorizations), destroy objects, etc, in these cases one possible approach is to use indirect references or change that id with a value that is not guessable.
5. Last but not less, you need to include proper passwords policies for your users you can look in other sites, or consult NSA for that kind of info.

In most cases security depends on the nature of your application, you may need some other security (for example if your logic includes external links/URLs you may want to check that those links are valid and safe, etc...), but as I said before I think that the list described above is a good fit for a good set of applications, the rest depends on your logic/flows, hope the above helps to clarify.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, but before i can mark it as answer, i just need to clarify that I'm using CanCan which prevents users from access stuff that they shouldn't access, and as for the SSL, it's going to be there in production, but still my question is by forcing SSL and adding the above headers, will that prevent access to the tokens sent on headers ? Specially the user token, it's JWT with expiry time, but it could be long enough so that the attacker can use it to access the API as this user, unless in missing somethibg else, I appreciate your patience with me :)

Comment: Also, will setting something like accept only requests from a specific IP adress or domain should be a good protection to block any incoming connection from unknown source or it's useless (I have no idea if someone can access using a fake IP adress or not)

Comment: @Amir El-Bashary , yes with forcing ssl connection (https traffic only), and also adding proper cors policy etc (that policy depends of your site), you will secure any data sent from your fronted app (Angular) to your API,  why? because by doing that you serialize all the traffic

Comment: So the above means that all info is going to be encrypted when the data left the browser of your client, also with the above configuration you are securing more than that, but be aware that you need to add/edit more config to the one above since some of the configurations depends mostly of your site.

Comment: And dont worry I hope the above helps, there is not too much info around securing API properly the above is not a silver bullet but I think is a really good start @Amir El-Bashary

Comment: Thank you again for clarifying that to me, I'll put everything mentioned above into consideration, it's not my first time to deploy an app to production, but it's my first time to deploy a new version of an app which has almost 1 million traffic daily and also a lot of competitors, that's why i thought i should have higher level of security :)

Comment: And one last question please, when I'm returning the user's JWT token in sessions API response, should i return it as normal string, to be set as cookie by the front-end client, or to be set as cookie by the rails API itself ?

Comment: That is a separate question @Amir El-Bashary, but in any case, your data will be serialized, and when you send anything from your front to your back or from your backend to your fronted you are sending text so, yes you can send it as a string

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your time, i almost got 80% of all my questions answered :)

Answer (score 1):

In production your client code should be communicating with your backend API with an SSL secured connection. Most of the time you would put an SSL certificate on a web server or load-balancer that is proxying your API or app server. This would prevent a middle-man from intercepting the token and then impersonating the user.

Edit: Also, maybe you need to clarify "My question here, with each request sent from angular, the token are exposed on headers and anyone can have access to them" - I'm curious how anyone could have access to these headers? Also your JWT should be signed and have an expire time set thats respected by the app server.

Comment: Because when we performed a test with no SSL on API server and front-end client, i could see the headers of the request on the network tab, I'm not sure if it's an issue on the frontend, since I'm not a frontend dev. That's what i meant by my question, and by signed, you mean signed cookies on the sessions API response?